# Runge Kutta method in VC++

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, runge-kutta

I am developing a algorithm for calculating new data points using the Runge Kutta Method. Here is the reference to implementing this method - http://calculuslab.deltacollege.edu/ODE/7-C-3/7-C-3-h.html. Here is my code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<math.h>
class Runge_Kutta
   {
     public:
             float x[100];
             float y[200];
             float h;         // step size
             float K_1,K_2,K_3,K_4;
             float compute();  // function to compute data point
             float data();   //function to generate data signal 
             Runge_Kutta();
             ~Runge_Kutaa();
    }
   Runge_Kutta::Runge_Kutta()
     {
       x[100] = 0;            // input signal
       y[200] = 0;            // output accumulator
       h = 0.2;
       K_1 = K_2 = K_3 = K_4 = 0;
      }
  ~Runge_Kutta::Runga_Kutta(){}

    float Runge_Kutta::data()
          {
            int i = 0;
            for(i=0 ; i<100 ; i++)
               {
x[i] = 5*sin((2*3.14*5*i)*0.01);  /*x[i] = A*sin(2*Pi*f*i*Ts)
               }                    Ts-sampling period, A-amplitude,
        return x[i];                f-frequency*/
       }

  float Runge_Kutta::compute()
     {
        int j = 0;
        int i = 0;
     for(i = 0 ; i<100 ; i++)       // indexing through the input samples
         {
           for(j = 0 ; j<i+1 ; j++) // compute data points btw i and i+1
               {
                   K_1 = h*x[i];
                   K_2 = h*((x[i]+(h/2) + K_1/2);
                   K_3 = h*((x[i]+(h/2) + K_2/2);
                   K_4 = h* ((x[i] + h) + K_3);
              }
           y[i] = (1/6)*(K_1 + 2*K_2 + 2*K_3 + K_4);  //new data value
          }
        return y[i];
        }

     int main()
          {
               Runga_Kutta Interpolate;
               Interpolate.data();
               Interpolate.compute();
               return 0;
          }
```

The problem is: y[i] is not storing the new data value and shows "0" or some junk value. Second problem is that, its not possible for me to increment the loop index value (x-axis) in terms of floating point as "h = 0.2" in this case. I used breakpoints to find the problem, but I am not able to figure it out and would need some help or direction in order to get over this. I have a feeling, that its due to some problem in my logic & implementation. Please review my code and suggestions on how to fix it would be of great help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `(1/6)` should probably use floating point constants not integers, e.g. `1.0/6`

Comment: Is the goal here to interpolate data points or to generate data points given and initial value for x and an equation dx/dt = f(x)? For interpolation, if linear isn't good enough then  [cubic spline](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spline_interpolation) could be used .

Answer (score 1):

You have several problems in your code... I'll point out what I see.

```
class Runge_Kutta
{
public:
    float x[100];
    float y[200];
    float h;         // step size
    float K_1, K_2, K_3, K_4;
    float compute();  // function to compute data point
    float data();   //function to generate data signal 
    Runge_Kutta();
    ~Runge_Kutaa();
};
```

So far, okay...

```
Runge_Kutta::Runge_Kutta()
{
    x[100] = 0;            // input signal
```

Here is your first problem. The `x` array is 100 floats, and you are trying to set the **101st**. Remember that C++ uses zero-based indexing, so the only valid indices are 0 to 99 inclusive. By writing to `x[100]` you are writing outside the array... probably into `y`, but certainly you should not do that.

More likely, you wanted to zero-initialize the entire array. There are different ways to create/initialize a sequence of values (e.g. vector, dynamic allocation), but as you've done it, the easiest is probably:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i) { x[i] = 0.0f; }
```

You would be better off creating a named constant to replace the "magic number" 100.  Continuing on with your code:

```
    y[200] = 0;            // output accumulator
```

Similar problem with `x` above. Again, I suspect you're trying to zero-initialize the whole array; replace with:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < 200; ++i) { y[i] = 0.0f; }
```

Then:

```
    h = 0.2;
```

This will work; you might get a warning about double to float conversion, since 2.0 is considered a double but you are storing a float. You can force a float literal by appending an `f`.

```
    h = 0.2f;
```

Continuing:

```
    K_1 = K_2 = K_3 = K_4 = 0;
}

~Runge_Kutta::Runga_Kutta(){}

float Runge_Kutta::data()
{
    int i = 0;
    for(i=0 ; i<100 ; i++)
    {
        x[i] = 5*sin((2*3.14*5*i)*0.01);  /*x[i] = A*sin(2*Pi*f*i*Ts)
    }                                       Ts-sampling period, A-amplitude,
    return x[i];                            f-frequency*/
}
```

Perhaps you did not actually use multiline comments (e.g. /* and */), but you are actually commenting out some code here... enough that it should not compile. If you are going to create block comments to the right of the code, make sure to use per line comments (e.g. // ).

Assuming you actually did that correctly, you have a bigger issue here. You first declare `i`, set it to zero, then use it as a loop index. In itself, that isn't a problem, though it is more idiomatic to loop with the type inside the `for`, like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i)
```

The biggest problem is accessing `x[i]` after the loop. `i` at this point is 100, and as before `x[i]` is outside the `x` array, which can only be indexed from 0 to 99. Did you mean to return `x[0]`? Which x did you want? Return that specific one.

```
float Runge_Kutta::compute()
{
    int j = 0;
    int i = 0;
    for(i = 0 ; i<100 ; i++)       // indexing through the input samples
    {
        for(j = 0 ; j<i+1 ; j++) // compute data points btw i and i+1
        {
            K_1 = h*x[i];
            K_2 = h*((x[i]+(h/2) + K_1/2);
            K_3 = h*((x[i]+(h/2) + K_2/2);
            K_4 = h* ((x[i] + h) + K_3);
        }
        y[i] = (1/6)*(K_1 + 2*K_2 + 2*K_3 + K_4);  //new data value
    }
    return y[i];
}
```

You may have confused your loop indicies in this section. (But I am not familiar with Runge-Kutta enough to know.)  Should `i` be the index for both `x` and `y`?  Where does `j` get used, and should it?

Finally, returning `y[i]` seems like it will have similar issues to the previous loop... As it is, you are only initializing `y` from 0 to 99, then you return `y[100]` (since i == 100 at end of that function).

If you are confused about any points I've made, I'll try to clarify; just ask.

EDIT: As was mentioned, (1/6) will evaluate (using integer division) to zero. Replace one or both constants with a floating-point to ensure floating-point division... e.g. `1.0/6`

So, you want access to all the data after calling `data()` or `compute()`... but right now you are returning a single `float` rather than the whole array.  Here are some options.

First, you've left `x` publicly accessible. Not usually recommended, but if this is learning or experimentation, because it is `public`, you can access that data directly.

```
Runge_Kutta Interpolate;
Interpolate.data();
Interpolate.compute();
for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i) {
    printf("Data point x[%d] = %f\n", i, Interpolate.x[i]);
}
```

You could change `data()` and `compute()` to return a pointer to the array, though generally this is also not recommended:

```
float* Runge_Kutta::data()
{
    // the bulk of the function...
    return &x[0];
}

// Use:
float* pData = Interpolate.data();
printf("First data signal: %f\n", pData[0]);
```

Another option is to provide indexed data accessors:

```
class Runge_Kutta {
public:
    // everything else you already have...
    float getDataSignal(size_t i) const {
        return x[i];
    }
    float getDataPoint(size_t i) const {
        return y[i];
    }
};
```

Even another option is to use containers from the C++ Standard Library, such as `vector`, which contains many convenient operations as part of the library.

Comment: I need access to each amplitude values corresponding to x[0], x[1], x[2].......till x[99] i.e. 100 sample values.

Comment: Access where? Returned from `data()`? You have options... I wouldn't recommend returning an array of 100 floats, but there are other ways. I'll add a bit to my answer to demonstrate.

Comment: In the compute() function, "i" is the index for acquiring each input sample values from x[i]. For example: when i = 0, the second loop starts initializing j = 0 and then computes values of K_1,K_2,K_3,K_4 followed by computing the value of y and storing it in it. And this happens in steps of 0.2 between i =0 and till j<i+1 i.e. 1. So the compute function computes new data values in steps of 0.2 between samples x[0] and x[1], then stores these values in y array.

Comment: And i need to get all the computed values stored in the y array.

Comment: yes, access to the values returned from data(). So that using these values I can compute the new data points to be stored in the y-array

Comment: To zero-fill without magic numbers, `for each (auto& yi : y) yi = 0;`

Comment: Also, careful about the myriad misspellings of Runge-Kutta (some appeared already in the question, and several not).  The compiler won't know you meant for them all to be the same class.

Comment: @BenVoigt Good point on the zero fill... Sadly, my daily C++ work is still in pre-C++11 land, so I forget some of the newer niceties.

Answer (score 0):

You should not complicate a situation by introducing additional constraints like having to interpolate a data set to obtain the system function.

```
RK::dydx(x,y) 
{
    return 5*sin(2*M_PI*5*x);
}
```

and use the correct transcription of the RK4 cookbook recipe

```
RK::step(x,y,h) 
{
    double K1 = h*dydx(x,y);
    double K2 = h*dydx(x+h/2, y+K1/2);
    double K3 = h*dydx(x+h/2, y+K2/2);
    double K4 = h*dydx(x+h  , y+K3  );

    return y+(K1+2*(K2+K3)+K4)/6
}
```

Then you can loop

```
for(i=0;i<100-1; i++) 
{
   y[i+1] = step(x,y[i],h);
   x +=h;
}
```

Comment: It seems the goal here is interpolation, not numerical integration of an ordinary differential equation.

Comment: Yes, that is the first sentence of the task description, "generating new data points". The remaining 90% are a badly contorted discussion of the Runge-Kutta method. Which of course is completely misplaced in an interpolation task.

Comment: Yes I need to generate new data values using the existing values of f(x,y) for x[0],x[1]...x[99]. I am trying to generate data values between the neighbouring samples in steps "h" that depends on the sampling factor.

Comment: If I need to interpolate, then I rather go about it by solving 4x4 system of linear equations(cubic polynomial) using the LU decomposition matrix method. However I presume that, generating new data values between neighbouring samples using RK4 by considering each existing data values as initial conditions, I can increase the number of data points or samples. Doesn't interpolation do the same? i.e. calculating the intermediate sample values from the existing one's?

Comment: RK4 applies to differential equations, `y'(x)=f(x,y(x))`. What is the differential equation you propose to solve?

Comment: You already have an equation for x(t) (x as a function of time), so RK4 isn't  useful. For interpolation, as mentioned above, use [cubic spline](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spline_interpolation).

Comment: @LutzL: I don't want to solve any differential equation. I got confused to thinking that RK4 and interpolation have the same purpose. I just need to estimate new intermediate data values and interpolate them.

Comment: @rcgldr: I am familiar with cubic spline and yes i will check it out. I taught I can get rid of solving 3rd order polynomial equations to interpolate by using RK4,  but I was wrong. And using matrix and implementing LU decomposition methods in C++ is a pain.